# Numerical Integration by Simpsons method

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve this integration by simpsons method and plot the result in a figure.The figure is taking only the value of P0= -6 from the for loop. When I set I(K,P) it gives the error:

> Attempted to access P0(0); index must be a positive integer or logical

How can I solve it?

```
alpha = 45;     
beta = 185;     
gamma_e = 116;  

% Gain values

G_ei = -18.96;    
G_ee = 18.52;
G_sr = -0.26;
G_rs = 16.92;
G_es = 2.55;
G_re = 4.67;
G_se = 0.73;
G_sn = 2.78;

G_esre = G_es*G_sr*G_re;
G_srs = G_sr*G_rs;
G_ese = G_es*G_se;
G_esn = G_es*G_sn;

t_0 = 0.085;    % corticothalamic loop delay in second
r_e = 0.086;    % Excitatory axon range in metre
f = linspace(-40,40,500);   % f = frequency in Hz
w = 2*pi*f;                 % angular frequency in radian per second
delt_P = 0.5;

L=zeros(1,500);
Q=repmat(L,1);
P=repmat(L,1);

%%%%%%%%%%%%% integration %%%%%%%%%%%%

a = -80*pi;
b = 80*pi;
n=500;

I=repmat(L,1);
P_initial = repmat(L,1);
P_shift = repmat(L,1);
p = repmat(L,1);

for k = 1:length(w)
    for P0 = [6 -6]

        L_initial = @(w1) (1-((1i*w1)/alpha))^(-1)*(1-((1i*w1)/beta))^(-1);                                                                 

        Q_initial = @(w1) (1/(r_e^2))*((1-((1i*w1)/gamma_e))^(2) - (1/(1-G_ei*L_initial(w1)))*....
            (L_initial(w1)*G_ee + (exp(1i*w1*t_0)*(L_initial(w1)^2*G_ese +L_initial(w1)^3*G_esre))/(1-L_initial(w1)^2*G_srs)));                  

        P_initial =  @(w1) (pi/r_e^4)* (abs((L_initial(w1)^2*G_esn)/((1-L_initial(w1)^2*G_srs)*....
            (1-G_ei*L_initial(w1)))))^2 * abs((atan2((imag(Q_initial(w1))),(real(Q_initial(w1)))))/imag(Q_initial(w1)));                   

        G =  150*exp(- (f - P0).^2./(2*(delt_P).^2));   

        P2 = @(w1) G(k) + P_initial(w1);

        L_shift =  @(w1) (1-((1i*(w(k)-w1))/alpha))^(-1)* (1-((1i*(w(k)-w1))/beta))^(-1);                               

        Q_shift  = @(w1)  (1/(r_e^2))*((1-((1i*(w(k)-w1))/gamma_e))^(2) - (1/(1-G_ei*L_shift(w1)))*...
            (L_shift(w1)*G_ee + (exp(1i*(w(k)-w1)*t_0)*(L_shift(w1)^2*G_ese +L_shift(w1)^3*G_esre))/(1-L_shift(w1)^2*G_srs)));     

        P_shift =  @(w1)  (pi/r_e^4)* (abs((L_shift(w1)^2*G_esn)/((1-L_shift(w1)^2*G_srs)*(1-G_ei*L_shift(w1)))))^2 *....
            abs((atan2((imag(Q_shift(w1))),(real(Q_shift(w1)))))/imag(Q_shift(w1)));                                

        p =  @(w1)  P2(w1)*P_shift(w1);        %  Power spectrum formula for P(w1)*p(w-w1)

        I(k) = simprl(p,a,b,n);

    end
end

figure(1)
plot(f,I,'r--')

figure(2)
plot(f,G,'k')
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you only use the results for `P0 = -6` as you save them in `I(k)`. First you save the result for `P0 = 6` later you overwrite it and save the other. The results of `P0 = 6`are neither used nor saved. If you write your code as follows this will be clarifyied.

```
for k = 1:length(w)

    L_shift =  @(w1) (1-((1i*(w(k)-w1))/alpha))^(-1)* (1-((1i*(w(k)-w1))/beta))^(-1);                               

    Q_shift  = @(w1)  (1/(r_e^2))*((1-((1i*(w(k)-w1))/gamma_e))^(2) - (1/(1-G_ei*L_shift(w1)))*...
        (L_shift(w1)*G_ee + (exp(1i*(w(k)-w1)*t_0)*(L_shift(w1)^2*G_ese +L_shift(w1)^3*G_esre))/(1-L_shift(w1)^2*G_srs)));     

    P_shift =  @(w1)  (pi/r_e^4)* (abs((L_shift(w1)^2*G_esn)/((1-L_shift(w1)^2*G_srs)*(1-G_ei*L_shift(w1)))))^2 *....
        abs((atan2((imag(Q_shift(w1))),(real(Q_shift(w1)))))/imag(Q_shift(w1)));           


    for P0 = [6 -6]
        G =  150*exp(- (f - P0).^2./(2*(delt_P).^2));   
        P2 = @(w1) G(k) + P_initial(w1);
        p =  @(w1)  P2(w1)*P_shift(w1);        
        I(k) = simprl(p,a,b,n);
    end
end
```

You can't access `I(k,P)` as `I` is an vector not an matrix. However this will give you *Index exceeds matrix dimensions.* You could save the results for `P0 = -6` in one variable and `P0 = 6` in the other variable as the results in your code do not depent on each other.

Comment: Thanks. It helps me a lot.